# MySql: OUT parameters always returns NULL

Tags: mysql

Below is my DDL for the stored procedure.

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bbt_admin.getNUM;
 CREATE PROCEDURE bbt_admin.`getNUM`(IN vUei CHAR(52),
                                    IN vNum VARCHAR(52), 
                                    OUT s VARCHAR(100),
                                    OUT e VARCHAR(100))
 BEGIN    
 SELECT       
    trim(concat(ns.PREFIX,ns.Num)) AS NUM,
    ns.COUNTRY_CODE AS COUNTRY_CODE
 INTO @s,
      @e
 FROM CUSTOMER cu
    join SITE si                     ON si.PARENT_ID =   cu.ID
    join NUM_RANGES nr               ON nr.SITE_ID = si.ID
    join NUMBERS ns                  ON ns.RANGE_ID = nr.RANGE_ID
    join ADDRESSES as saddr          ON si.ID = saddr.UEI
    join PROVISION_SETTING as ps     ON ps.UEI = si.ID
 WHERE (cu.ID = vUei OR si.ID = vUei)
    AND ( ns.OWNER NOT LIKE  'sub%' OR ns.OWNER IS NULL )
    AND ns.NUMBER_CLASS in (1,5,9)
    AND trim(concat(ns.PREFIX,ns.Num))= vNum;
END;
```

And when I execute the mysql stored procedure it executes successfully but the output parameters always contain NULL value. Please find below statements used to call the stored procedure and to select the OUT parameters values:

```
 CALL getNUM('customer:11', '012124215421', @s, @e);                    
 select @s, @e;
```

I get the OUT parameter values when I run the SELECT statement separately as below but executing stored procedure always returns OUT parameters with NULL value

```
  SELECT       
    trim(concat(ns.PREFIX,ns.Num)) AS NUM,
    ns.COUNTRY_CODE AS COUNTRY_CODE
  INTO @s,
       @e
  FROM CUSTOMER cu
    join SITE si                        ON si.PARENT_ID = cu.ID
    join NUM_RANGES nr                  ON nr.SITE_ID = si.ID
    join NUMBERS ns                     ON ns.RANGE_ID = nr.RANGE_ID
    join ADDRESSES as saddr             ON si.ID = saddr.UEI
    join PROVISION_SETTING as ps        ON ps.UEI = si.ID
  WHERE (cu.ID = 'customer:11' OR si.ID = 'customer:11')
   AND ( ns.OWNER NOT LIKE  'sub%' OR ns.OWNER IS NULL )
   AND ns.NUMBER_CLASS in (1,5,9)
   AND trim(concat(ns.PREFIX,ns.Num))= '012124215421';
```

Can you please help me out to solve this problem.                                         Thanks in advance